# WAMI Recorder in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, flash, voice-recording

I'm looking at this flash audio recorder:
http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

Has anyone successfully implemented it in .NET (specifically MVC3 C#)? All I see in the site is PHP implementation without an actual demo site.

Also, if anyone has good alternatives for voice recording, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is setup the recordUrl and playUrl

as a basic implementation you can do something like this:

```
@{
    var payUrl = "http://yourdomain/recordings/recording-" + Session["recordingId"] + ".wav";
    <!-- saves the wav file to local folder called recodings using a session value to make unique file names -->
}
<script>
        function setupRecorder() {
            Wami.setup({
                id: "wami",
                onReady: setupGUI
            });
        }

        function setupGUI() {
            var gui = new Wami.GUI({
                id: "wami",
                recordUrl: "http://yourdomain/home/Save",
                playUrl: "@payUrl"
            });

            gui.setPlayEnabled(false);
        }
</script>
```

and add the save action in your home controller

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
    Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/recordings/recording-" + Session["recordingId"].ToString() + ".wav"), false);
    return Json(new {Success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code in your page:

```
<div id="wami"></div>
```

And the following in its code behind:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "setupRecorder", "setupRecorder();", true);
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

Create a web page, say **RecorderPage.aspx**, leave the html empty and put the following in the code behind:

```
private const string Path = "/App_Data/recordings";
private static readonly string FileName = string.Format("audio-{0}-{1}.wav", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), Guid.NewGuid());
private static readonly string Directory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string mapPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(Path);
    string action = Request.QueryString["action"];
    if (!action.HasValue()) {
        return;
    }
    if (action.Equals("save")) {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Directory)) {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Directory);
        }
        Request.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path + "/" + FileName), false);
    } else if (action.Equals("play")) {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "audio/x-wav");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "audio/x-wav";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        Response.WriteFile(mapPath + "/" + FileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Expires = -1;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Make sure all the required files are correctly imported (buttons.png, gui.js, recorder.js and Wami.swf).

Finally, include these two functions in the script portion of your page, modifying `recordUrl` and `playUrl` according to your configuration:

```
function setupRecorder() {
    Wami.setup({
        id: "wami",
        onReady: setupGUI
    });
}

function setupGUI() {
    var gui = new Wami.GUI({
        id: "wami",
        recordUrl: "http://localhost/RecorderPage.aspx?action=save",
        playUrl: "http://localhost/RecorderPage.aspx?action=play"
    });

    gui.setPlayEnabled(false);
}
```